# VMware Workstation can't start automatically at startup

Tags: startup, vmware

I want to run VMware Workstation and have it start a guest machine automatically when starting up Ubuntu. Unfortunately I tried to add

```
vmware -X my.vmx
```

to Startup applications, and also [this method](http://www.atrixnet.com/autostart-vmware-virtual-machines-on-boot-in-linux/), but none of them works: Vmware silently does not run at startup, and there is no entry containing `vmware` either in `/var/log/boot.log` or `/var/log/dmesg`. What can the problem be?

Comment: Did you configure your script in the method you linked? VM_list & VM_user.

Comment: Does the command work if you try it on a terminal?

Comment: @boon Yes, I correctly configured these variables.

Comment: @i08in Yes, I tried it.

Comment: You tried it, does it work as intended?

Comment: Yes, it works when executing manually from Terminal but not as a startup application.